# Adding Java Dates as keys on maps

Tags: java, collections

Java 8 here, although I'm dealing with `java.util.Date`, *not* `LocalDate`.

I have a situation where I need to create a `Map<?,?>` where the keys are `Dates`:

```
Map<Date, List<Fizz>> fizzesBySpecialDate = new HashMap<>;
List<Fizz> fizzes = getFizzesSomehow();

for (Fizz fizz : fizzes) {

  Buzz buzz = getBuzzFromFizz(fizz);

  if (fizzesBySpecialDate.containsKey(buzz.getSpecialDate())) {

    fizzesBySpecialDate.get(buzz.getSpecialDate()).add(fizz);

  } else {

    final List<Fizz> newGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    newGroup.add(fizz);

    fizzesBySpecialDate.put(buzz.getSpecialDate(), newGroup);

  }

}
```

So my *intention* is for all `Fizzes` who have a `Buzz` with the same `specialDate` (e.g. 7/4/2019) to be mapped together. However, since each `getBuzzFromFizz()` will return a `Buzz` with a new `Date` instance, none of the `Dates` will be the same instance, and so I don't believe the above will work.

What I need is a way to say: "*Does this map already contain the same String date as the new String date of this current `Buzz`?*". Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: So because you “don't believe the above will work” you ask us to help you fixing a problem that you only believe to exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the key from `buzz.getSpecialDate()` to  formatted string date without time. And you will be easily able to group the fizzes.

e.g. Key could be YYYY-MM-dd format Date

You can use `DateFormat` for same.